# wireshark heuristic dissector decode as a part of the packet

Tags: lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I wrote a ixia lua dissector. I have same problem with other similar dissector.

Yes i know there is dissector already written in c, but it doesn't work out of the box, at least not for my trace  - and i also tried the workaround proposed to "Fixed ethernet trailer length" to 19. Perhaps didn't work because my packet is tunneled so i have 2 ethernet layers.

I succeeded to parse the ixia trailer.

My problem is that the eth_trailer crc is parsed by my dissector

With the added code, the crc now appear before the layer of ixia, instead under the ethernet layer tree. Is there a possibily to show the crc under ethernet layer as for packet without ixia?

```
if offset_ixia == 4 then 
    local subtree = tree:add(ixia_trailer_proto, buffer(0,offset_ixia),"eth.trailer")   
end

local subtree = tree:add(ixia_trailer_proto, buffer(offset_ixia,length-offset_ixia),"Ixia trailer")
```

[image: ethernet trailer crc before ixia]

In regular packet it look like the follwoing:

[image]

Here is full simplified code to show the problem:

```
ixia_trailer_proto = Proto("ixia_trailer","Ixia-lua Trailer")

-- Header fields
source = ProtoField.uint8("ixia_trailer_proto.source"    , "Source"    , base.HEX)
ixia_trailer_proto.fields = {source}
offset_ixia = 0

-- create a function to dissect it
local function is_ixia_trailer(buffer,pinfo,tree)
    local length = buffer:len()
    --eth + ip
    if length < 15 then return false end
    if length == 15 then 
        type_offset = 11
    elseif length == 19 then -- 15 + crc size
        type_offset = 15
        offset_ixia = 4
    end
    local type = buffer( type_offset , 2):uint()
    if type == 0xaf12 then  
        ixia_trailer_proto.dissector(buffer, pinfo, tree)   
        return true 
    end

    return false
end

function ixia_trailer_proto.dissector(buffer, pinfo, tree)
    length = buffer:len()

    if offset_ixia == 4 then 
        local subtree = tree:add(ixia_trailer_proto, buffer(0,offset_ixia),"eth.trailer")   
    end

    local subtree = tree:add(ixia_trailer_proto, buffer(offset_ixia,length-offset_ixia),"Ixia trailer")

    subtree:add(source, buffer(offset_ixia + 0,1))
end

ixia_trailer_proto:register_heuristic("eth.trailer", is_ixia_trailer)
```

Here is a pcap file example with the trailer https://transfernow.net/019rp7t214kv

Comment: Can you share a capture file somewhere?

Comment: The only way I can think of to possibly make this work reliably is to request a new link-layer header type which looks like an Ethernet frame but with an additional fixed 15 bytes at the end for the Ixia trailer.  See https://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html.  An explicit link-layer type could allow all but the last 15 bytes to be handed to the Ethernet dissector so it dissects the the FCS properly, and then afterwards the trailing 15 bytes could be handed to the Ixia trailer dissector.  I don't know, maybe there's another way to accomplish what you're after, but I can think of anything.